# Triangle inequality on the projective space

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces, projective-space

Given a unit $n$-sphere $\mathbb{S}^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : \langle x,x \rangle = 1\}$, we define the set $\mathbb{P}^n = \{[x] : x \in \mathbb{S}^n\}$, where $[x] = \{-x, x\}$, and a function $d: \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $$d([x],[y]) = \min\{\|x-y\|, \|x+y\|\}.$$

I am to prove that $d$ is a distance function in $\mathbb{P}^n$. The exercise should be simple, but I can't figure out how to show that the triangular inequality holds, that is: $$d([x], [y]) \leq d([x], [z]) + d([z], [y]) \qquad\forall [x],[y],[z] \in \mathbb{P}^n.$$  Given two vectors $u,v \in \mathbb{S}^n$, I can say if $d([u], [v])$ is equal to $\|u-v\|$ or $\|u+v\|$ using the angle between the vectors, but separate the problem in different cases hasn't helped. I think there could be a more direct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Let $z$ be any representative of $[z]$.
2. Let $x$ be a representative of $[x]$ such that $d([x],[z])=\|x-z\|$.
3. Let $y$ be a representative of $[y]$ such that $d([z],[y])=\|z-y\|$.

Now the desired inequality becomes 
$$d([x], [y]) \leq \|x-z\| + \|z-y\|$$
and the rest should be clear.

Answer (score 2):

*No need to check for special cases.*

First note that $|x-z|=|x+y-(z+y)|\leq|x+y|+|z+y|$. Then,
\begin{align*}
2\cdot d([x],[z])&\leq|x-z|+|x+z|\\
&\leq|x+y|+|y+z|+|x-y|+|z-y|\\
&=\big(|x+y|+|x-y|\big)+\big(|z+y|+|z-y|\big)\\
&\leq2\cdot\big(d([x],[y])+d([y],[z])\big)
\end{align*}