# Metric in the projective space $P^n$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, projective-space

Let $S^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}; \langle\, x,x\rangle = 1 \}$.

$P^n$ is the set of all unordered pairs $[x] = \{x,-x\}$, $x \in S^n$.

I'd like to prove that $d([x],[y]) = \min \{\|x-y\|,\|x+y\|\}$ is a metric.
I'm having trouble with the triangle inequality.

I looked at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200314/triangle-inequality-on-the-projective-space) and I found the answer didn't clarify the situation for me.

It  should be simple, but I didn't understand the steps 2 and 3 in the answer. Why is it possible to choose such representation of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: If your question is a question about that solution, you should first ask the solution's author there. That user happens to be very active, so you should have some luck.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
\begin{align*}
d([x],[z])&=\min(||x-z||,||x+z||)\\
&\leq \min(||x-z||+||y-z||,||x+z||+||y+z||)\\
&\leq \min(||x-z||,||x+z||)+\min(||y-z||,||y+z||)
\end{align*}
Where the second line is true because we add a positive number to positive numbers and as such the minimum must be greater and the last one is fairly self evident.

Answer (score 0):

First note that $|x-z|=|x+y-(z+y)|\leq|x+y|+|z+y|$. Then,
\begin{align*}
2\cdot d([x],[z])&\leq|x-z|+|x+z|\\
&\leq|x+y|+|y+z|+|x-y|+|z-y|\\
&=\big(|x+y|+|x-y|\big)+\big(|z+y|+|z-y|\big)\\
&\leq2\cdot\big(d([x],[y])+d([y],[z])\big)
\end{align*}